# {"Could not load type 'VBR.Pipeline.Domain.ExpertGuide' from assembly 'Pipeline, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an application using NHibernate, all my classes and mappings work and I can retrieve data with no problem, until I decided to add a new table in the database (and new class, mapping in the code).

I keep getting the error that my class can't be found in the assembly.

My Class is called ExpertGuide, Mapping file ExpertGuide.hbm.xml (already an embedded resource)

I cleaned, rebuilt, etc the project and nothing.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: turn on assembly binding logging on and check the poath it is searching for the assembly. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/255669/671619

Comment: Thank you, I had a problem with the namespace of the class I was using namespace Pipeline.Domain when the namespace should have been VBR.Pipeline.Domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the namespace of my class, I had Pipeline.Domain instead of VBR.Pipeline.Domain so my class couldn't be found